# Should we honor Zoe's election by burninating the [zoe] tag referring to a deprecated tool?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I was celebrating the election of our new moderator, Zoe, when I stumbled across a tag named after her: [zoe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zoe)!

This tag only has one question. According to its tag wiki:

> Zoë is an open source tool for generating spritesheet images and frame data from SWF files, and part of the CreateJS suite.

However, according to [the official website](https://createjs.com/zoe) of Zoë, the tool has been deprecated since July 2018.

> Support for Zoë has been deprecated. Consider Adobe Animate's native animated Spritesheet support

It seems like this is the perfect time to burninate [zoe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zoe).

Comment: *"According to the official website of Zoë, the tool has been deprecated since July 2018."* -  Why is that relevant to burninating it? Just because things are deprecated doesn't mean people stop using them.

Comment: Please refer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/4826457 for burnination request criteria. So far this one doesn't meet any of them.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Discord.py is obsolete, but we still get a lot of questions about it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We don't burninate tags because they refer to technology that has been deprecated. Plenty of people still use deprecated and even *obsolete* technology.

That said, the question looks off-topic for Stack Overflow, so it should probably be closed.

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure that it's off-topic - maybe I'm being obtuse (or it's too late at night), but I was somewhat confused from the documentation whether this is a programming library or a stand-alone tool (and whether someone other than a programmer would actually use it).

Comment: It looked to me like a standalone tool, @EJoshuaS, despite the fact that you did find the source code publicly available. I suppose if someone were asking about it as a library, that'd be fine, but the question I see doesn't seem to be about it in that context. Something to export SWF files doesn't seem like it is within the domain of software tools primarily used by programmers, either. But I'm open to counter-arguments from someone more familiar with this.